# How to create a portable library class targeting Windows Phone 8 without installing the Windows Phone 8 SDK?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-8, portable-class-library

I would like to create a portable library class targeting **Windows Phone 8** from a Windows 2008 R2 machine with *Visual Studio 2010* on it and without Windows Phone 8.0 SDK installed.

From Visual Studio 2010, there are only these options available:

[image]

Is there a *multi-target* package for Visual Studio to install that supports Windows Phone 8 target framework?

**Note:**
Since Windows Phone SDK 8 requires Windows 8, it can't be installed on this kind of development workstation (back-end oriented).

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible. WP8 requires VS2012 and Windows 8. I got the same problem in the past.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the WP8 SDK specifically.  The simplest thing to do would be to use Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 or later.  You may also be able to install a later version of the Portable Library Tools for VS 2010 to get most of the PCL WP8 support.